# JQuery Sortable - Nested Handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, handle

I'm using jquery sortable to drag and drop blocks on a page. However I'm having problems witht the handle.

The html of a block is like so :

```
<div class="row insumo-editor-module" style="">
    <div class="span12 module-toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-remove-module"><i class="icon-remove-circle icon-white"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-move-module"><i class="icon-move icon-white"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- More html here -->        
</div>
```

The javascript to make it sortable is the following (each .insumo-editor-module is contained in editor_zone which is a div).

```
editor_zone.sortable( {
    handle: '.btn-move-module',
    cursor: 'move',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    opacity: 0.4,
}).disableSelection();
```

I've tried using a link directly in .insumo-editor-module as the handle and it worked fine. I've also removed the handle attribute completely and it works. However, trying to use .btn-move-module isn't working.

Is there any way of using nested html as a handle?

There is a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xonorageous/neexj/6/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you passing a jQuery object to the handle ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to put that there, I orginally just tried
handle: '.btn-move-module' but it didn't work, so I started playing around with it.

Comment: One more thing, why do you want an actual <button> element as a handle ? I assume you are using bootstrap to style it ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the btn-group class to style the toolbar for each module. The button is inside the toolbar

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle in the question

Comment: Because by default buttons are not draggable, see in [jquery docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel), and i think you could make them draggable, but if you can style any element as a button then that would be better solution,imo (btw fiddle looks great :) )

Comment: ok rusln, thanks for the answer. I'll try replacing the button with something else

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. You can have the handle nested inside other elements without a problem. By replacing the  with a standard anchor link the sortable items are now moving without any problems.

Thanks to rusln for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your nested html to `<li>` tags inside `<ul>` and make ul as sortable.

Also take a look at `items` option on [jquery.ui sortable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/):

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ items: ".row" });
```

Comment: Hi alexey, thanks for the answer. You don't need to have a list for sortable to work, with div's it is already working. If I remove handle from my call to sortable, it works fine. My problem is just trying to use .btn-move-module as the handle